# Design compromise in using decorator

Tags: design-patterns, wrapper, decorator

There is an existing functionality with below pseudo code

```
class MyMessageSink implements MessageSink {
        public void sendToFulfillment();
}
```

Now, I would like to add transaction & locking capability to the `sendToFulfillment` method. I did this using wrapper pattern

```
class TransactionalMessageSink{
      private MessageSink sink;
      public TransactionalMessageSink(MessageSink sink){
                this.sink = sink;
          }
       public void sendToFulfillment(){
            //start transaction
            sink.sendToFulfillment();
            //end transaction     
        }
}
```

Similarly, I created a `LockingMessageSink` and the client code became

```
new LockingMessageSink(new TransactionalMessageSink(new MyMessageSink())).sendToFulfillment
```

However, the transaction & locking code is very less, simple and straightforward (since we are using a framework which does most of the boilerplate work for us). So I though of another approach -

```
class MyMessageSink implements MessageSink {
            public void lockAndSendToFulfillmentInTransaction(){
                    //locking start
                     sendToFulfillmentInTransaction();
                    //locking end
            }

            public void  sendToFulfillmentInTransaction(){ 
                     //transaction start
                      sendToFulfillment();
                     //transaction end
            }
            public void sendToFulfillment();
    }
```

The problem here is obvious, there is a tight coupling between the locking and transaction code but avoids creation of 2 additional classes for simple functionality.

I personally like the first approach, but still am not convinced that this is the best one.

My question - Is there a better way other than using Wrapper, i.e any efficient way to handle these in a single class without compromising on the design aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_oriented_programming).  If you are using Java, take a look at [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/)

Transactions and other "aspects" such as logging are known as cross-cutting concerns that need to be implemented in multiple designs and abstractions.  AOP can be used to automatically wrap your methods with boilerplate to do transactions or logging etc.

Comment: Thank you, I think this perfectly fits the bill here. However, thinking ahead, assuming that these were not system requirements (like transaction , logging) and were rather application requirements - in that case will AOP still be the best bet? since I believe AOP is mostly used for implementing System Requirements and not Application Requirements